# Error: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory in android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, kotlin

I am trying to create a file on the file system, but I still get this exception:

```
private fun getTempFolder(): File {
        val directoryFolder =
            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample-take-image")
        directoryFolder.mkdirs()
        return directoryFolder
    }
    private fun getTempFile(): File {
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHMMss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        return File(
            getTempFolder().absolutePath,
            "image".plus(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis).plus(timeStamp).plus(".jpg")
        )
    }
    private fun saveImageToFile(bitmap: Bitmap? = null): String? {
        return try {
            val file = getTempFile()
            Timber.e("Path: + : ${file.absolutePath}")
            file.createNewFile()
            val fOut = FileOutputStream(file)
            bitmap?.apply {
                this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut)
            }
            fOut.flush()
            fOut.close()
            file?.absolutePath.getDefault()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            ""
        }
    }
```

Even though I got the link after taking the photo camare:

**: /storage/emulated/0/sample-take-image/image162064003789420210510_160517.jpg**

So can someone tell me why I can't create the file in this case. I am currently on **Android 11**
with

**compileSdkVersion 30

```
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

minSdkVersion 26**
```

Comment: `directoryFolder.mkdirs()` Bad coding. Better: `if ( ! directoryFoldes.exists() if ( !directoryFolder.mkdirs()) return;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On An Android 11 device you cannot create directories or files in root of external storage.

But you can  in all public directories that are already there.

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample-take-image")
```

Replace for instance by:

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "sample-take-image")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `getExternalMediaDirs()` (methods on Context), instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` as this is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
String dirPath;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                dirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "/";
            } else {
                dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "/";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Case, permission was missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also request to Allow the Storage Permission in the App Setting